# Empty content screen shows every single time

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I have an EmptyContentFavorite() screen, which I want to show only when the screen is really empty. But here EmptyContentFavorite() screen shows every single time while clicking that. How can I achieve show just when the screen is empty?

**Here is my code example:**

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun FavoriteScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: FavoriteViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {

    val state = viewModel.state.value

    val books = state.books
    var currentSortOrder by remember { mutableStateOf<SortOrder>(SortOrder.DateDescending) }
    val sortedBooks = when (currentSortOrder) {
        SortOrder.DateDescending -> books.sortedByDescending { it.timestamp }
        SortOrder.DateAscending -> books.sortedBy { it.timestamp }
        SortOrder.PageCountIncrement -> books.sortedBy { it.pageCount.toInt() }
        SortOrder.PageCountDecrement -> books.sortedByDescending { it.pageCount.toInt() }
        SortOrder.Shortest -> books.sortedBy { it.bookName.length }
        SortOrder.Longest -> books.sortedByDescending { it.bookName.length }
    }
    
    val isLoading by viewModel.isLoading.collectAsState()
    val swipeRefreshState = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing = isLoading)
    


    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            FavoriteTopBar(navController = navController)
        },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 45.dp)
    ) {

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))

        SwipeRefresh(
            state = swipeRefreshState,
            onRefresh = {
                viewModel.getBooks(BookOrder.Date(OrderType.Descending))
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp)
        ) {

// Actual code starts here
            if (books.isNotEmpty()) {                
                LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
                    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                        top = 50.dp,
                        bottom = 50.dp
                    ),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    verticalItemSpacing = 16.dp
                ) {
                    items(sortedBooks) { book ->
                        FavoriteItem(
                            book = book
                        )

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    }
                }
            } else {
                EmptyContentFavorite()
            }



        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun EmptyContentFavorite() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.red_heart),
            contentDescription = "no favorite",
            modifier = Modifier.size(96.dp)
        )
        Text(text = "You have no favorites!")
    }
}
```

**This is the video sample for actual problem**:
[Because of reputation you can watch from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZbCw.gif)

Comment: Try to make state.books under remember { }

Comment: It doesn't work, even now my favorite items don't show on favorite screen itself

Answer (score 0):

You're populating the screen while the state is still loading. `books` will be empty until the value is retrieved from the state. You can include a check for `isLoading` to account for this. If the state is still loading, display a loading screen so the user will see that instead of the "no favorites" view.

Something like:

```kotlin
// Actual code starts here
if (isLoading) {
    // Loading screen goes here
} else {
    if (books.isNotEmpty()) {                
        LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
            columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                top = 50.dp,
                bottom = 50.dp
            ),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            verticalItemSpacing = 16.dp
        ) {
            items(sortedBooks) { book ->
                FavoriteItem(
                    book = book
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            }
        }
    } else {
        EmptyContentFavorite()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Rob, it works on me when there is at least 1 favorite item, but if there is not, it shows a blank screen instead of EmptyContentFavorite()